# Plot abscissa points

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

I have been instructed to plot abscissa points. This is new to me, even the concept is alien to me. I have a set of data, where S is the x-axis and res the y-axis. The goal is to plot a figure where the y-values are abscissa points with step size 1. I hope I make myself clear as this is new vocabulary for me. This picture below show what I want, but for the case of 3 different results.

[image]

My data is

```
S   res
0.0609  6.7704
0.2329  6.2444
0.2450  6.2129
0.3614  5.9381
0.3695  5.9208
0.3874  5.8832
0.5407  5.5962
0.6937  5.3617
0.8068  5.2139
0.8800  5.1277
0.9417  5.0601
1.0426  4.9583
1.0596  4.9421
1.3909  4.6730
1.7260  4.4673
1.7819  4.4379
1.8029  4.4271
2.3595  4.1906
3.5557  3.8780
3.8134  3.8310
3.9931  3.8011
4.1521  3.7764
4.2312  3.7646
4.3542  3.7471
4.8955  3.6785
5.0500  3.6612
5.3198  3.6329
5.4694  3.6183
5.5042  3.6150
5.6136  3.6048
5.9022  3.5795
5.9254  3.5776
6.2234  3.5538
6.5877  3.5272
6.7547  3.5158
6.8985  3.5064
6.9526  3.5030
7.3203  3.4808
7.3491  3.4791
7.6427  3.4628
7.8028  3.4544
7.8861  3.4501
8.2681  3.4316
8.6863  3.4130
8.8786  3.4049
9.1432  3.3944
9.3339  3.3871
9.4376  3.3832
9.6991  3.3739
10.1324 3.3593
10.3367 3.3528
10.3872 3.3513
10.4576 3.3491
10.8189 3.3384
10.9081 3.3359
11.2106 3.3276
11.3095 3.3250
11.3511 3.3239
11.4378 3.3216
11.6254 3.3168
11.6436 3.3164
12.0040 3.3076
12.0999 3.3053
12.7600 3.2907
12.9767 3.2862
12.9839 3.2860
13.2933 3.2799
13.5121 3.2756
13.7759 3.2707
14.1185 3.2646
14.9172 3.2513
15.2656 3.2459
15.3575 3.2445
15.8158 3.2379
15.9012 3.2367
15.9566 3.2359
16.4394 3.2294
16.8287 3.2244
17.0825 3.2212
17.5011 3.2162
17.5183 3.2160
17.8230 3.2125
18.0421 3.2101
18.2244 3.2081
18.2769 3.2075
18.5387 3.2047
19.0181 3.1998
19.2317 3.1977
19.3171 3.1969
19.3596 3.1965
19.7607 3.1927
20.2166 3.1885
20.5085 3.1860
21.6216 3.1768
21.8692 3.1749
22.1848 3.1725
22.2096 3.1723
22.3483 3.1713
23.6573 3.1622
24.2929 3.1581
25.0191 3.1537
25.0860 3.1533
25.4832 3.1510
26.0507 3.1479
26.4090 3.1459
27.0138 3.1428
27.1195 3.1423
27.3474 3.1411
27.6732 3.1395
27.9499 3.1382
27.9999 3.1379
28.3672 3.1362
28.6554 3.1349
29.0878 3.1329
30.0215 3.1289
```